# How can I target lightning:icon and change its color?

Tags: javascript-controller

What I want to accomplish is to show 5 stars in each row of a table. The users then can rate each row separately using the stars. However I just cant find out how to target the stars using the controller.

This is what i have in a lightning component:

```
    <div aura:id="starsArea" onclick="{!c.rateArea}">
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:favorite" size="xx-small"/>
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:favorite" size="xx-small"/>
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:favorite" size="xx-small"/>
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:favorite" size="xx-small"/>
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:favorite" size="xx-small"/>
    </div>
```

Controller code :

```
({
    rateArea : function(component, event, helper) {
        var element = event.target;
        var child = element.firstChild;
        console.log('child ' + child); // null
        console.log('target ' + element.nodeName); // div
    },
})
```

When I click a star the DIV wrapping the lightning:icons is targeted and if I count the children of a DIV nothing is to be found.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you saying you want to capture the icon details in the JS?

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to manipulate the icon. Imagine that u have 5 stars from left to right u want to color first three stars if the third star was clicked.

Comment: Have you tried putting an *aura:id* on respective icons and then fetch that in the JS using *component.find('iconid')* and see if that works?

Comment: I added some details around how you can manipulate using *aura:id*. If that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to get the details of the icon in your JS controller. Assuming that to be the case, you can use **[aura:id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm)** on each of your icons and then retrieve those in your JS function.

So your markup looks as below with each icon declared with a unique id:

```
<div aura:id="starsArea" onclick="{!c.rateArea}">
    <lightning:icon aura:id="icon1" iconName="utility:favorite" size="xx-small"/>
    // all other icons with unique aura:id...
</div>
```

Now in your JS controller, you can fetch the details as:

```
var icon1 = component.find("icon1"); 

// you can verify say the iconName as below
console.log(icon1.get("v.iconName");

// now let's say I want to change the icon type, I can set that right this way
icon1.set("v.iconName","utility:activity"); // this will change my icon on component.
```